# Is a particular countable subset of the Cantor set Polish?

Tags: real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

Consider the Cantor space $\mathcal{C} := \{ 0, 1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and the subset $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ of sequences that start with $1$ and eventually "terminate" with $0$, i.e. $\mathcal{T} = \{ (1,0,0, \dots,), (1,1,0, \dots), \dots \} = \{ x \in \mathcal{C} \mid \exists K: \forall k \geq K: x_k = 0 \wedge \forall k < K: x_k = 1 \}$.

Is $\mathcal{T}$ Polish with the induced subspace topology of $\mathcal{C}$?

Properties of $\mathcal{T}$:

- $\mathcal{T}$ is countable and thus and $F_\sigma$-subset of $\mathcal{C}$
- $\mathcal{T}$ is not closed in $\mathcal{C}$
- $\mathcal{T}$ can also be seen as a disjoint union of Polish spaces (the singletons) and thus Polish as well. But I don't see how to write it as a $G_\delta$-subset of $\mathcal{C}$? Or is the disjoint union topology on $\mathcal{T}$ a different one as the subspace topology in this case (as is similar to the case of the rationals as a countable subset of the reals)?

Comment: The last bullet point is false. The union of infinitely many Polish spaces is not necessarily Polish, or else *every* space would have been Polish as a union of singletons. More to the point, $\Bbb Q$ is *not* Polish, take from this what you will about the space you're looking at right now.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was noting in the third bullet as well. The disjoint union topology is in general not the induced subspace topology. In particular, the disjoint union topology of discrete spaces is discrete. But I see now, that singletons in $\mathcal{T}$ are not open in $\mathcal{T}$ since $\mathcal{T} \cap O$ is not a singleton for every open $O \subseteq \mathcal{C}$. So one should try to create some homeomorphism from $\mathcal{T}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes. And remember that the rational numbers is the only (metric)  space which is countable and without isolated points.

Comment: Wait, I'm getting confused now. Set $B := \{ 0, 1 \}$. The Cantor set $\mathcal{C} = B^{\mathbb{N}}$ has the product topology and thus $O := \{ 1 \} \times \{ 0 \} \times B \times B \times \dots$ is open in $\mathcal{C}$ and thus $\mathcal{T} \cap O = \{ (1,0,0,\dots) \}$ is an open neighborhood of $(1,0,0,\dots)$ in $\mathcal{T}$. Therefore, $(1,0,0,\dots)$ is isolated. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, $(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,\ldots)$ is also in that intersection.

Comment: But this is not an element of $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh, I am terribly sorry. :-) I thought that $\cal T$ was all the eventually $0$, not the finitely many $1$'s and then $0$'s all the way. Yes, my previous suggestion to find a homeomorphism with $\Bbb Q$ should be taken with a grain of salt. Terribly sorry 'bout that. :-)

Comment: No probs, the precise definition of $\mathcal{T}$ is as above, but I should have verbalized it more precisely. I was just searching for the representation as a $G_\delta$-subset which I didn't see directly.

Comment: So, can you find the open sets on your own now?

Comment: Let's try. The singleton $\{ (1, 0, 0, \dots) \}$ is a $G_\delta$-subset of $\mathcal{C}$ since it is the countable intersection of the open sets $\{ 1 \} \times \{ 0 \} \times B \times B \dots$, $\{ 1 \} \times \{ 0 \} \times \{ 0 \} \times B \times B \times \dots$, etc. A finite union of $G_\delta$'s is a $G_\delta$: $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} O_i \cup \bigcap_{j \in \mathbb{N}} O_j = \bigcap_{(i,j) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}} (O_i \cup O_j)$. But a countable union is not necessarily a $G_\delta$, it is a $G_{\delta \sigma}$. So I'm still not there :).

Comment: Try to draw a picture (and this is one of the only times I'll ever say that). You're close. But any actual hint will just give you the answer.

Comment: I think to have found the idea. Instead of intersecting the $G_\delta$'s from the above comment inductively we can do it simultaneously (due to the fact that ARBITRARY open sets are open, so we take such a (countable) union BEFORE performing the induction). In more detail: $10BBB\dots \cup 110BB\dots \cup 1110BB\dots \cup \dots$ is a disjoint union of open sets around the points of $\mathcal{T}$ but also $100BB\dots \cup 1100BB\dots \cup 11100BB\dots \cup \dots$ is an open set, etc. When we intersect these countably many open sets we get precisely $\mathcal{T}$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: As an alternative to Asaf's suggestion in the comments, observe that every Polish space is a Baire space (why?), and consider $\bigcap_{x\in\mathcal{T}}(\mathcal{T}\setminus\{x\})$.

**Added:** Oops! That hint was based on the same misreading that Asaf had, i.e., that $\mathcal{T}$ is the set of sequences beginning with $1$ that are eventually $0$. In fact your $\mathcal{T}$ is a discrete subset of the Cantor set: it's not hard to find nbhds of the points of $\mathcal{T}$ that witness this fact. (Alternatively, show that if $x_n$ is the member of $\mathcal{T}$ beginning with exactly $n$ ones, then the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges in the Cantor set and therefore is discrete.)

Comment: That's not really the right answer, since I probably misread the definition of $\cal T$ and influenced your reading of it.

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks! I was also influenced by the OP's first comment.

Comment: I see, $\mathcal{T}$ is discrete since an open nbhd of $(1,0,0,\dots)$ is $\{ 1 \} \times \{ 0 \} \times B \times B \times \dots$ which does not contain any other point of $\mathcal{T}$. Similarly for the other points in $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: @yadaddy: Yes, that's the direct argument.

Answer (score 2):

You could use automata theory (see Thm I.6.2, I.9.9 and III.3.11 from [this book](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jep/Resumes/InfiniteWords.html)) to solve your question.

Let $X$ be a subset of $\{0,1\}^\omega$. Then the following conditions are
equivalent:

1. $X$ is a countable intersection of open sets,
2. There exists a subset $L$ of $\{0,1\}^+$ such that $X=\overrightarrow{\!L}$,
   where 
   $$
    \overrightarrow{\!L} = \{u \in \{0,1\}^\omega \mid u \text{ has infinitely many prefixes in }L\},
   $$
3. $X$ is accepted by a deterministic Büchi automaton.

Since $1^+0^\omega = \overrightarrow{1^+0^+}$, the set $1^+0^\omega$ is a countable intersection of open sets and hence is Polish.

**Remark**. If $X$ is $\omega$-regular, like your example $1^+0^\omega$, you may assume in (2) that $L$ is a *regular* language and in (3) that $X$ is accepted by a *finite* deterministic Büchi automaton.